# BQ2057WSN Circuit Heating issue

Tags: power-supply, pcb-design, battery-charging, power-electronics, heatsink

We are using BQ2057WSN charging IC to charge a 7.4V, 6600mAh Li-Ion Battery by providing 12VDC,2A power supply.  According to my calculation the charging current is set at 625mA. But while charging, the BQ2057 charging IC and the mjd32ct4-a (the NPN trasistor) is heating up. Any drawback in my design? I am attaching the images below.

[image: Schematic]
[image: BQ2057WSN Circuit]
[image]

Comment: Any device that passes energy heats up. So, that's not a problem per se. How much power dissipation are you expecting? How much do you expect the transistor to heat up? How much is it heating up instead?

Comment: @MarcusMüller, The FET(Q1) is dissipating 3.825W power and the it raises the temperature of the FET case upto 90 degree Celsius. I want the case temperature below 40 degree Celsius. I think the FET cannot dissipate the heat and all the heat is localized within the FET. What could be the possible solution of it?

Comment: use a different FET

Comment: Earlier I am using FZT788B. It was heating around 100 degree Celsius. After that I have used MJD32CTA, but still it is heating about 90 degree Celsius. Should I replace the Transistor by a MOSFET? Will it be fine? What should be the minimum required thermal resistance of the FET to reduce the heat?

Comment: Aakash, you *designed* that circuit. **You** hence have chosen the transistor according to your calculations of waste heat, switching capabilities and speed, would be what I expect. So, go back and look into your formulas: find the source of the heat. It's probably voltage drop in the ON state, but maybe also in the transition between ON and OFF.

Comment: According to my calculation, the thermal resistance ( junction to Ambient) of the FET should be 25 degree/Watt and the required board area is 9 sq. inch. But I am not able to find any FET having such thermal resistance.